# Importing data from multiple sheets dynamically and sort by date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G9-lVE15VlOUhMM_OVOn-Xwi7fmJHz-FNJdVVnwBCYI/edit#gid=2100307022

I need to import a range of data from another spreadsheet which has many sheets, I have a cell which contain the references to the spreadsheet and a column that list the all the sheet where I need to retrieve the data from. I am able to retrieve the data from a single sheets or type the sheets into the formula manually, but I need it to be done dynamically.

Using

ARRAYFORMULA(
IF(F2:F<>"", IMPORTRANGE(G2, F2:F&"!A3:Q"), "")
)

I was able to do what I need but the data spread across multiple row which causes an overlapping error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try this base formula which you can wrap inside your existing `query` part:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(F2:F,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,importrange(G2,c&"!A3:Q"))))
```

- *make sure `importrange` is properly linked by granting permission to access source sheet*

[image]

Comment: I only need the data from column 1,2,17,3,8 and sort them by column 2 which is a date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: `=query(<above_reduce_formula>,"Select Col1,Col2,Col17,Col3,Col8 Where  Col2 is not null order by Col2 DESC")`